# Implementing arrays for a Palindrome program

Tags: arrays

I am working on creating a program that reads strings in from a data file calles "palindromes.txt" and which stores the strings in a one-dimensional array. The program is supposed to inspect each of the strings and detrmine whether or not each one is a pallindrome. It's supposed to show output on the screen and into a file called "output.txt".

The problem i'm having is that I can't figure out how to get the input/output correct and i'm not sure the best way to utilize the arrays.

Very new to this, please advise if you can. :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindromes2 
{
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String dirtystr) 
    {
        dirtystr = dirtystr.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
        int length = dirtystr.length(), middle = length / 2;
        for (int x = 0; x < middle; x++)
            if (dirtystr.charAt(x) != dirtystr.charAt(length - x - 1))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File inputFile = new File("output.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile)) 
        {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
            {
            String dirtystr = scanner.nextLine();

            if (isPalindrome(dirtystr)) 
                {
                    System.out.println(dirtystr + " IS a palindrome.");
                } 
            else 
                {
                    System.out.println(dirtystr + " is NOT a palindrome.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working, exactly? What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed with the arrays. The code itself at the moment runs fine and determines the palindromes. But i'm supposed to be reading one file and sending output to another. And at the same time use a one-dimensional array. Any suggestions?